# Use of For loop in processing directory contents in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, tagging

I am attempting to loop through a series of text files in a directory, looking for occurences of certain types of words, and prefixing each found word with a user defined tag.  My code is as follows.

```
ACC_Tagged_Test = 'C:/ACC_Tag_Test'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(ACC_Tagged_Test, '*.txt')):
 with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = data.lower()

modals = {"could":1, "would":1, "should":1, "can":1, "may":1, "might":1}
personal_attribute = {"believes":1, "guess":1, "surmise":1, "considers":1, 
"presume":1, "speculate":1, "postulate":1, "surmised":1, "assume":1}
approx_adapt = {"broadly":1, "mainly":1, "mostly":1, "loosely":1, 
"generally":1, "usually":1,"typically":1, "regularly":1, "widely":1}
plaus_shields = {"wonder":1, "suspect":1, "theorize":1, "hypothesize":1, 
"cogitate":1, "contemplate":1, "deliberate":1}

format_modal = "<555>{} ".format
format_attribute = "<666>{} ".format
format_app_adaptor = "<777>{} ".format
format_plaus_shield = "<888>{} ".format


data = " ".join(format_modal(word) if word in modals else word for word in data.split())

data = " ".join(format_attribute(word) if word in personal_attribute else word for word in data.split())

data = " ".join(format_app_adaptor(word) if word in approx_adapt else word for word in data.split())

data = " ".join(format_plaus_shield(word) if word in plaus_shields else word for word in data.split())

with open (filename, "w") as f:

 f.write(str(data))
 print(data) # This is just added in order to check on screen all files
              # Are being processed.
```

My problem is that although code works on the last file in the directory it is not working on the previous files (1 out of 10 in this)  I've tried a second For loop above the file write out statements but that is not working at all.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

regards

Comment: It would help if you indented the code properly so we can be sure of what's in the for loop and what is not.

Comment: Why does the For... loop at the beginning of the code not work all the way through the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My speculation is your code is only showing the last file because it's
>   not indented properly to have all relevant code within the for loop.

**Try with this indentation:**

```
ACC_Tagged_Test = 'C:/ACC_Tag_Test'

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(ACC_Tagged_Test, '*.txt')):
  with open(filename) as f:
      data = f.read()
      data = data.lower()

  modals = {"could":1, "would":1, "should":1, "can":1, "may":1, "might":1}
  personal_attribute = {"believes":1, "guess":1, "surmise":1, "considers":1, 
  "presume":1, "speculate":1, "postulate":1, "surmised":1, "assume":1}
  approx_adapt = {"broadly":1, "mainly":1, "mostly":1, "loosely":1, 
  "generally":1, "usually":1,"typically":1, "regularly":1, "widely":1}
  plaus_shields = {"wonder":1, "suspect":1, "theorize":1, "hypothesize":1, 
  "cogitate":1, "contemplate":1, "deliberate":1}

  format_modal = "<555>{} ".format
  format_attribute = "<666>{} ".format
  format_app_adaptor = "<777>{} ".format
  format_plaus_shield = "<888>{} ".format


  data = " ".join(format_modal(word) if word in modals else word for word in data.split())

  data = " ".join(format_attribute(word) if word in personal_attribute else word for word in data.split())

  data = " ".join(format_app_adaptor(word) if word in approx_adapt else word for word in data.split())

  data = " ".join(format_plaus_shield(word) if word in plaus_shields else word for word in data.split())

  with open (filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(str(data))
    print(data) # This is just added in order to check on screen all files
                # Are being processed.
```

Comment: It works like a charm with the small test set I'm using.  Will run it on a larger version tomorrow, but thanks very much for your help.  Can you explain why indentation is so important in Python?  Is it similar to using curly brackets in languages such as C# and Java?

Comment: @Cerberus_64--yes, Python uses indentation for code blocks rather than curly brackets of other languages.  The advantage of this it forces writing code which is more readable by others.  [More here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all of your code is supposed to be in your for loop. You are overriding your text file, therefore it looks like only your last run is working:

```
#this overrides the file
with open(filename, "w") as fh:
    fh.write(str(data))
```

change to:

```
#this append to the file
with open(filename, "a") as fh:
    fh.write(str(data))
```

This will append to your text file and will not override previous added data with the data from the last loop.

Comment: Your modifcation is just appending the updated file to the original file.  I need each text file in the directory to be read, processed and written back to the same directory, before moving to the next file and the next etc.

Comment: oh, sorry I must have miss understood what you were trying to achieve. So you want each file to be processed and overridden with your data?

Comment: That's correct, I'm not understanding why the for loop is not working.